# What is the difference between python.exe, python3.exe, and python3.6.exe?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation

I just installed the 64 bit edition of ActivePython 3.6, and discovered that it contains three executable files that report identical version information and are the same size, but not entirely identical, peer fc.exe. I have

- python.exe
- python3.exe
- python3.6.exe

Though I could probably use something along the lines of ProcMon to figure out whether python.exe is just a stub, but before I expend that much effort, I thought that I would inquire here.

Please be forewarned that I'll be posting this same question, under exactly the same title, on The Code Project, on the assumption that its audience doesn't completely overlap this one.

Comment: Just call each of these in cmd to see the interpreter output. It might be possible, that these are python2.7, python3.5 and python3.6. The version info will be the output at the top.

Comment: The PSF distribution of Python for Windows doesn't use versioned executable names. Using such names is the norm on Unix systems, but in that case `python` is usually Python 2.x. As to whether these are stubs, on Windows the executable handles parsing the command line, but the interpreter and built-in modules are in pythonXY.dll. If you have a tool such as dumpbin.exe, you can see this dependency in the executable's DLL imports.

Comment: I was aware of the convention on Unix systems, and suspected that might be the case. The reports generated by dumpbin are identical, as are the responses given in a command window. I ran all three through UltraCompare, which reported only a handful of differences, all of which appear to be literals stored in tables near the end of the file. I think it's safe to say that they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all interchangeable, so no worries. They are needed for compatibility based on different system setups. ActivePython has a long history and builds on multiple platforms, so all precautions are taken.